# Not able to include Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface in constructor

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, addtocart, rest-api

I am trying to add multiple configurable products to cart using a custom REST API request. For that I call the existing save function for each products. I'm able to add upto product options. But when I try to add extension attributes, it's is not working as expected. Instead of that, I'm getting error message
`"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\CartItemExtensionInterface in ../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:9`

Whenever I try to include `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface` in constructor, this error message is alone occurs. I am doing like below

```
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface;

class MultiItemsCart extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository implements MultiItemsCartInterface
{
    /**
     * Quote repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;
    protected $serviceProcessor;
    protected $quoteItemRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory
     */
    public $cartItem;
    public $productOption;
    public $extensionAttributes;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor $serviceProcessor,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository $quoteItemRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ProductOptionInterface $productOption,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes,
        array $cartItemProcessors = []
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->serviceProcessor = $serviceProcessor;
        $this->quoteItemRepository =$quoteItemRepository;
        $this->itemDataFactory = $itemDataFactory;
        $this->cartItem = $cartItem;
        $this->productOption = $productOption;
        $this->extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes;
    }
    /**
    * Returns greeting message to user
    *
    * @api
    * @param mixed $cartItems
    * @return array
    */
    public function multiItemsCart($cartItems) {
        foreach($cartItems as $cartItem){
            $this->cartItem->setSku($cartItem['sku']);
            $this->cartItem->setQuoteId($cartItem['quote_id']);
            $this->cartItem->setQty($cartItem['qty']);
            $this->cartItem->setProductOption($this->productOption);
            //$this->cartItem->setExtensionAttributes($this->extensionAttributes);
            $this->quoteItemRepository->save($this->cartItem);

        }
        return $cartItems;
    }
}
```

I tried to include the same class in some other class also, there also I'm getting same error message. Can any one help on this...

Comment: You miss the namespace? Or just not post here?

Comment: not posted here

Answer (score 2):

According to [Magento 2 Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/app/code/Magento/Quote/Api/Data), There are no file called `CartItemExtensionInterface.php` inside `app/code/Magento/Quote/Api/Data/`. So if you want to use this, you can use [CartItemInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/app/code/Magento/Quote/Api/Data/CartItemInterface.php#L161) then call a function  `getExtensionAttributes()`. So that in your code, rewrite the `__construct` like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor $serviceProcessor,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository $quoteItemRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ProductOptionInterface $productOption,
    array $cartItemProcessors = []
) {
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->serviceProcessor = $serviceProcessor;
    $this->quoteItemRepository =$quoteItemRepository;
    $this->itemDataFactory = $itemDataFactory;
    $this->cartItem = $cartItem;
    $this->productOption = $productOption;
    $this->extensionAttributes = $cartItem->getExtensionAttributes();
}
```

Also, delete the line `use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionInterface;`.

Comment: I need to setExtensionsAttributes using the array I have. When I set like this $this->cartItem->setExtensionAttributes($cartItem['product_option']['extension_attributes']); I am getting error Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Item::setExtensionAttributes() must be an instance of Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\CartItemExtensionInterface, array given

Comment: You may try this: `$this->cartItem->setExtensionAttributes($cartItem->getExtensionAttributes());`

Comment: Still Error
Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getExtensionAttributes() on array

Comment: Did you clear `var/generation` folder?

Comment: yes...cleared var/di and var/generation

Comment: Try to var_dump `$cartItem` and see if there are an key called `ExtensionAttributes`

Comment: It is NULL...in response

Comment: It's OK to receive NULL. Extension Attributes are just extra custom attributes in an cart item. If there are no Extension Attributes, then it receives NULL value. Of course if you suppose have extra attributes, you should get an array.

Comment: I have extension attributes in the post request {
   "cartItem": {
      "quote_id": 76,
      "sku": "test",
      "qty": 5,
      "product_option": {
         "extension_attributes": {
           "configurable_item_options": [
               {
                  "option_id": 206,
                  "option_value": 3946
               },
               {
                  "option_id": 207,
                  "option_value": 11737
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}

Comment: You should check the input of this function, maybe sth missing.